# TFS Build fails to copy to drop location

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Building my solution succeeds, but the build fails upon copying from the build to the drop location. I get an error like this

```
TF270002: An error occurred copying files from 'E:\Workspace' to '\\server\drop location_20101026.25'. 
Details: Access to the path '\\server\drop location_20101026.25\_PublishedWebsites\website\bin\somecompiled.dll' is denied.
```

This is a part of a continuous integration build (as well as several other types of build that I've tried). This is a copied build definition from a definition that has worked for several months now, running on TFS 2010.

Comment: if you try to access that location manually from the TFS server, will you have access? May be there was changes in network?

Comment: I can access the files and folders fine after seeing the message. I forgot to mention that this is an intermittent error. I'd disabled Norton antivirus on those folders to try and prevent that from being the culprit (no luck).

Comment: Pretty sure I caused this myself as I had tweaked the workflow to use a parallel foreach container which would deploy various built websites to development servers, so I think i was running into contention with robocopy. I'll know for sure tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I was right, I did this myself by putting the copy to drop location task in the parallel foreach loop, resulting in the task being done 3 times, and causing my problems.